# How do I read physical memory in WSL 2?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

how do I read physical memory (/dev/mem) in WSL 2? (I want to read Windows RAM from the WSL)
https://shanetully.com/2014/12/translating-virtual-addresses-to-physcial-addresses-in-user-space/
I tried what this guy did, but instead of writing I read at that address. The read function didnt return -1, but I didn't read anything. So I tried if I can even read /dev/mem

```
cat /dev/mem | wc
cat: /dev/mem: Permission denied
      0       0       0
```

It appears that access is denied, any ideas how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: You may need to run this as `sudo`

Comment: @RyanNerd it looks like running it as sudo just increases the ram usage over time (30-40 mb per sec)

Comment: Looks like the Kernel will need to be recompiled for you to do this: "Linux provides direct access to the memory of a system through the /dev/mem block device. However, due to obvious security implications, no one can read from, let alone write to, this file, even as root. This is due to the CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM kernel config option. Being a config option, it must be set at compile-time so to change it, you’ll have to recompile your kernel."

Answer (score 0):

you ran that command without root permissions , 
so in order to get the Syntax OK you need to do the following like this:

$ sudo cat /dev/mem | wc